# metal macOS configure the storageMode of descriptor

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, applet, metal

I was trying the MetalImageRecognition example on macOS.

But:

```
**failed assertion `[MPSTemporaryImage prefetchStorageWithCommandBuffer:imageDescriptorList:] Error: the descriptor must be configured with MTLStorageModePrivate'**
```

when running

```
MPSTemporaryImage.prefetchStorage(with: commandBuffer, imageDescriptorList: [sid, inid, m0id, m1id, m2id, m3id, m4id, m5id, m6id, m7id, m8id, m9id, m10id])
```

I looked at the official document and tried to set the mode to be private:

```
let sid   = MPSImageDescriptor(channelFormat: textureFormat, width: 299, height: 299, featureChannels: 3, **storageMode: MTLStorageModePrivate**)
```

but

```
**Use of unresolved identifier 'MTLStorageModePrivate'**
```

Does anyone know how to set configure the storage mode?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, it's `MTLStorageMode.private` or just `.private` where type inference is possible.